# Joins with multiple tables using criteria builder

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data, criteria-api

I have 5 tables, the entities are shared below. First there is a buyerbusiness and supplier tables.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buyer_business")
public class BuyerBusiness {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "buyer_id")
    private Long buyerId;
    
    // Getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier")
public class Supplier {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;
    
    // Getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "process_order")
public class ProcessOrder {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer_business_id")
    private BuyerBusiness buyerBusiness;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "items_id")
    private Item item;
    
    // Getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "items")
public class Items {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
    private Supplier supplier;
    
}
```

The processOrder table is matched to supplier through the items table. It is also matched to purchaseorder table, but since that is not required here, I'm not adding the entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_supplier_mapping")
public class BusinessSupplierMapping {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
    private Supplier supplier;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer_business_id")
    private BuyerBusiness buyerBusiness;
    
    @Column(name = "deleted")
    private boolean deleted;
    
    // Getters and setters
}
```

The businessSupplierMapping table connects the business and supplier. This is the table that is causing the issue. I cannot make any db changes, like adding `Set<BusinessSupplierMappings>` in BuyerBuisness or Supplier entities.

I'm using criteria builder to build this query:

```
SELECT sum(amount),supplier.company_name FROM purchase_order 
     LEFT JOIN process_order ON process_order.id=purchase_order.process_order_id 
     LEFT JOIN items ON items.id=process_order.items_id 
     LEFT JOIN supplier ON items.supplier_id =supplier.id  
     LEFT JOIN business_supplier_mapping on business_supplier_mapping.supplier_id=supplier.id and business_supplier_mapping.buyer_business_id=process_order.buyer_business_id 
WHERE (purchase_order.deleted is null OR purchase_order.deleted is false) AND purchase_order.received_date 
    BETWEEN '2022-12-31 18:30:00' AND  '2023-06-23 18:29:58' and  process_order.buyer_business_id =   10  and 
    purchase_order.purchase_order_status = 'PROCESSED'  and business_supplier_mapping.deleted is false   
    group by items.supplier_id ;
```

Here is my code:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<PurchaseOrder> root = query.from(PurchaseOrder.class);
        Join<PurchaseOrder, ProcessOrder> processOrderJoin = root.join("processOrder", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<ProcessOrder, Items> itemJoin = processOrderJoin.join("items", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<Items, Supplier> supplierJoin = itemJoin.join("supplier", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<ProcessOrder, BuyerBusiness> buyerBusinessJoin = processOrderJoin.join("buyerBusiness", JoinType.LEFT);
        
    Join<ProcessOrder, BusinessSupplierMapping> businessMappingJoin = processOrderJoin.join("buyerBusiness", JoinType.LEFT);
    businessMappingJoin.on(builder.equal(processOrderJoin, businessMappingJoin.get("buyerBusiness")));
    Join<BusinessSupplierMapping, Items> supplierMappingJoin = itemJoin.join("supplier", JoinType.LEFT);
    supplierMappingJoin.on(builder.equal(supplierJoin, supplierMappingJoin.get("supplier")));

    query.groupBy(itemJoin.get("supplier").get("id"));
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        Predicate deletedPredicate = builder.or(
            builder.isNull(root.get("deleted")),
            builder.isFalse(root.get("deleted"))
        );
        predicates.add(deletedPredicate);
        if(businessReportRequestDTO.getFromDate()!=null && businessReportRequestDTO.getToDate()!=null){
            Predicate receivedDatePredicate = builder.between(
                root.get("receivedDate"), businessReportRequestDTO.getFromDate(), businessReportRequestDTO.getToDate()
             
            predicates.add(receivedDatePredicate);
        }

       
        Predicate buyerIdPredicate = builder.equal(buyerBusinessJoin.get("buyer"), buyerId);
        predicates.add(buyerIdPredicate);
        Predicate statusPredicate = builder.equal(root.get("purchaseOrderStatus"), PurchaseOrderStatus.PROCESSED);
        predicates.add(statusPredicate);
        Predicate deletedMappingPredicate = builder.isFalse(businessMappingJoin.get("deleted"));
        predicates.add(deletedMappingPredicate);
        Predicate deletedMappingPredicate1 = builder.isFalse(supplierMappingJoin.get("deleted"));
        predicates.add(deletedMappingPredicate1);

    query.multiselect(
        builder.sum(root.get("amount")),
        root.get("supplier").get("companyName")
     );
    query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));

    TypedQuery<Object[]> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
    List<Object[]> result = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

The resulting query is:

```
select sum(purchaseor0_.amount) as col_0_0_, supplier9_.company_name as col_1_0_ from purchase_order purchaseor0_ 
left outer join process_order processord1_ on purchaseor0_.process_order_id=processord1_.id 
left outer join items items2_ on processord1_.items_id=items2_.id 
left outer join supplier supplier5_ on items2_.supplier_id=supplier5_.id 
left outer join supplier supplier6_ on items2_.supplier_id=supplier6_.id 
left outer join buyer_business buyerbusin7_ on processord1_.buyer_business_id=buyerbusin7_.id left outer join buyer_business buyerbusin8_ on processord1_.buyer_business_id=buyerbusin8_.id, supplier supplier9_
where purchaseor0_.supplier_id=supplier9_.id 
    and (purchaseor0_.deleted is null or purchaseor0_.deleted=0) 
    and (purchaseor0_.received_date between ? and ?) 
    and buyerbusin7_.buyer_id=10 and purchaseor0_.purchase_order_status=? and buyerbusin8_.deleted=0 
    and supplier6_.deleted=0 group by items2_.supplier_id
```

I'm not able to add the business_supplier_mapping in the Join query. Any idea how to add that? Thanks!